# Some TableView views are not reloading, as my TableView Delegate is not receiving tableView:viewFor:row: for every row

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a `TableView`, and a `TableViewController`

The `TableView's` `delegate` and `datasource` are set to the `TableViewController`

So when the table goes to draw, it asks the delegate for the views, and this code runs:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    let result = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "flagView", owner: self) as? TableCellView

    case "technicalFlag", "supplyFlag":
        let button = result?.control as? NSButton {
            button.state = value.boolValue ? NSOnState : NSOffState
        }
     }
```

Which updates the buttons properly:
[image]

Notice how there are 5 flags for Technical Risk

However, when I go to sort by Supply Risk, it calls `tableView.reloadData()`

But, not every view gets reloaded?

As a result, some of the flags stay black, even when they shouldn't be (notice 8+ black flags in Technical Risk, now)

[image]

It's seemingly random which flags are black (when I look at the data via another view via context menu, I can tell which flags should truly be black)

So ostensibly, it looks like a redrawing issue.  I've tried everything, but can't get those views to redraw.  Am I missing something?

I've confirmed that `tableView:viewFor:row:` is just not getting called as many times as I think it should

I guess, to sum things up, I thought that calling `reloadData()` would update every view at every row x column?  How does the runtime decide which views get the update call?

Comment: How did you check if `tableView:viewFor:row:` is called for every visible cell? Which cells are skipped? Which flags are wrong? Does the same thing happen with the Supply Risk column?

Comment: I printed log statements at the very beginning of the method, same thing happens with the other column, and I'm not sure which flags are wrong, it seems kinda random.  I could reduce the amount of data and try to get a better idea of which ones are wrong though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah solved it, I had modified the original code because I didn't think it was relevant to show:

```
    case "technicalRiskFlag", "supplyRisk":
        if let value = node.value(forKeyPath: identifier) as? NSNumber,
        let button = result?.control as? NSButton {
            button.state = value.boolValue ? NSOnState : NSOffState
        }
```

But turns out that `value` could be `nil`, which ended up not redrawing the flag.  Not sure why the delegate method didn't get called still, but I changed the code to this:

```
        if let button = result?.control as? NSButton {
            if let value = node.value(forKeyPath: identifier) as? NSNumber {
                button.state = value.boolValue ? NSOnState : NSOffState
            } else {
                button.state = NSOffState
            }
        }
```

and it works perfect now